# What can be done about Closed Questions spoiling the questions page?

Tags: feature-request

I find it irritating to see a closed question on the questions page. It shouldn't be there, it spoils the smooth running of the site. It makes me want to... trample all over it. Perhaps a  tag could be put on the question and it put at the bottom of the questions queue so that people can find closed questions if they want. Perhaps there's another more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4):

Closures can be reversed (by a moderator or by 5 users with 3k+ reputation) and they *do* happen error, so it is proper that they should receive some attention.

Comment: I agree that they deserve _some_ attention but the OP's point remains: surely we could find a more elegant solution.. Actually I feel this is one small aspect of **a more drastic overhaul of the site's organizational structure** that IMO is getting more and more overdue.

Comment: OK, so perhaps a subtle link on the main page to closed questions would be a better compromise.

Answer (score 1):

I would support closed questions to be tagged as closed, so people can put them into their ignored tags. If the question is reopened, the tag can be removed.

Comment: The team are [firmly against "meta tags"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and [closed] would be exactly that.

Comment: ok i see. seems reasonable.