# Avoid display of closed questions

Tags: support, feature-request, closed-questions, search

I routinely check for new questions with tags I follow, using https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tab=Newest&tagMode=Watched. Given my Watched tags, that list often is clogged with closed questions. Can I remove closed questions from that list display? Some option "only show open questions" somewhere?

I trust folks here, so if a question got closed, I don't want to be bothered with it anymore. Would make my stackexchange experience a lot more fun without those distractions.

Comment: Hmm, just found that I can use closed:0 in the search bar. That works for that. Now I just need to find a way to marry that with the url for the Watched tags sorted by newest...

Comment: Essentially the same as [this mother meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7913/263383)

Comment: @ACuriousMind: True! Shall I close this question?

Comment: [related](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/802/what-can-be-done-about-closed-questions-spoiling-the-questions-page?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If doing a search, you can simply add closed:0

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to combine "my watched tags" with "closed:0". There [have been requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7913/263383) that the display of closed questions would be one option in the filters but this is currently not implemented.

In the absence of that, the next best thing is to first use the URL in the question to get the expanded search term. Add closed:0 to that search term, and voila. If your list of watched tags is rather long, you, like me, may be running against limitations e.g. in the search bar. But with a bit of manual editing you can create a lengthy, static URL that looks like this

```
https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=[tag_1]+or+[tag_2]+...+or+[tag_n]+closed:0
```

and that works. Obviously and unfortunately, this URL doesn't update when your list of watched tags changes.